# Specialism or/vs speciality

Tags: word-usage, nouns, synonyms

I had never heard of **specialism** until I encountered it in some British professional bodies' databases I was researching. I had thought it was a fake word because **speciality** would be the noun we use for what somebody specialises in.

Is there any distinction between specialism and speciality? Or may I start boasting about how "toast is my specialism in the kitchen"?

Comment: You may do what you like, but if you do so and then burn my toast, I'm going to hold your feet to the flames-- or toaster.

Comment: Please consult a good dictionary. Nothing fake.

Comment: @Nancy is toasting someone.

Comment: What does CED have to say (eg [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/specialty))? 'Specialty' should also be considered.

Comment: @Kris Yes note that "I had thought" it wasn't a word until I looked up a dictionary and then wanted to know if there was any difference between the two and hence the question. Please consult a course on past perfect.

Comment: Huh, Haroldus?!

Comment: Now here is one word that is in fact used  in British English, esp. in medicine to mean what in the US is called a specialty.

Answer (score 2):

I, as a British English speaker, would use *speciality* for something like your most successful dish, and *specialism* for the area of study an academic concentrates on, or the branch of medicine a *specialist* works in.

Comment: Interesting point.  I am in the US and have never heard of *specialism*.  However, we certainly have medical *specialists*.The topic a specialist specializes in?  I admit is would seem strange to call it a *specialty*.  In the US we probably say *specialization*.  "I am an M.D."  "Oh, What is your specialization?"  "Cardiology."

Answer (score 0):

I came across the word "specialism" in one of Ann Cleeves Shetland mystery books, Cold Earth.  In the passage in which the word appears, it's an American who is saying the word, but I've never heard that word used in the United States.  I'm almost 69 years old and have been an avid reader since I was a child, so if it was used here, I would have heard or read it. We would use the word specialty instead.

In the same book, in the same passage, Cleeves has that American character also saying  "I think he must have done."  Americans would not say that;  instead, we would simply say:  "I think he must have." I am very much an Anglophile, so I delight in noticing and learning these little differences between British and American speech. I guess to someone else, these differences might be a trivial, boring matter, but to me it's fun, like figuring out a crossword puzzle.

Comment: Ditto never hearing the word used in the US.